# Handling WCF events in another process

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, process, wcf-client

I have a non-serializable object that I would like to access from a separate process. I've looked around and it seems the only viable option is to use WCF but I'm not sure how to do this as I'm new to WCF. If I create a WCF service, how do I 'hook' the WinForm into the various events in the WCF service? For example, the user communicates with the WCF service directly and I would likemy WinForm client to be notified. How would I be able to know when the user has done something with the WCF service and have the WinForm client pick up on that?

Comment: i think you should try WCF full duplex service. but you will have to create some logic to audit actions and transmit them to your winform app

Comment: I am not sure why using WCF will allow you to access a non-serializable object from another process?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh - I'm new to WCF but looking at full duplex, it seems that it's a contract between the user and the service. The WinForm client is third party and doesn't call the WCF service directly.

Comment: @hugh - If the service maintains the non-serializable object then other processes can talk to the service to access the object. Unless there's another way you know of sharing objects between processes? It seemed WCF was the popular way of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way to achieve what you are looking for is to implement a callback contract on your service. Then your win-forms app would be able to "subscribe" to events fired on the service (such as modifications to your object).

To do this you implement a service contract with a callback contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService_Callback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NotifyClients(string message);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyService_Callback))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe();
}
```

You then implement your service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private List<IMyService_Callback> callbacks;

    public MyService()
    {
        this.callbacks = new List<IMyService_Callback>();
    }

    private void CallClients(string message)
    {
        callbacks.ForEach(callback => callback.NotifyClients(message));
    }

    public bool Subscribe()
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyService_Callback>();

        if (!this.callbacks.Contains(callback))
        {
            this.callbacks.Add(callback);
        }

        // send a message back to the client
        CallClients("Added a new callback");

        return true;
    }
}
```

In your winforms client you only need to implement the callback method:

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public partial class ServiceClient : Form, IMyService_Callback
{
    // Sync context for enabling callbacks
    SynchronizationContext uiSyncContext;

    public ServiceClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //etc.

        uiSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // Create proxy and subscribe to receive callbacks
        var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyService>(typeof(ServiceClient), "NetTcpBinding_IMyService");
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel(new InstanceContext(this));
        proxy.Subscribe();
    }

    // Implement callback method
    public void NotifyClients(string message)
    {
        // Tell form thread to update the message text field
        SendOrPostCallback callback = state => this.Log(message);

        uiSyncContext.Post(callback, "Callback");
    }

    // Just updates a form text field
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        this.txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + message;
    }
}
```

Config for service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="TestService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="Normal">
      <endpoint 
        address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService" 
        contract="TestService.IMyService" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Normal" >
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Config for client

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService" 
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="TestService.IMyService"
              name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The code is not actually working - will update with working code as soon as possible. But the general pattern is correct.

Comment: Code now works - had to replace the ChannelFactory with DuplexChannelFactory on the client.

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading up on that :D The pattern was the key aspect as I can Google my way around any errors. Thanks a lot for your help