# capture events from windows service

Tags: windows-services, msmq

I built a Windows Service, let's call it Jobs. And I have a WinForm app, let's call it Viewer.

I want Viewer to receive events from Jobs when Jobs starts executing something so Viewer can display to the user that Job A started, did something, stopped, etc.

Is there a way to have Jobs throw events that Viewer can register to receive?  The best solution I can think of is using MSMQ, however I'd like a more direct approach where I startup Viewer and it registers with the Jobs windows service and asks to receive notifications/events from it.

I can't seem to figure out how to get a Windows Service to Push something without using MSMQ, or to have others programs register with it to receive Pushes.  I definitely do NOT want to use some weird file and/or database system where Viewer sleeps for 5 seconds and then checks for changes.  I want something streamlined where Viewer Waits for Events, but does not have to use the MSMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the WCF duplex bindings for this, such as netTcpBinding or dualHttpBinding. There is a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897600/569662) which would seem to do exactly what you want.

The drawback is that duplex is complex to understand and may not be that reliable. I would always implement a solution using one way communication (either via queueing or some other mechanism) if it was an option to do so. One way is always simpler and more reliable than duplex.